# Proving a limit exists using delta and epsilon?

Tags: limits

First time posting, I did calculations, would someone be so kind to see if i'm right or wrong, i'm a part-time student so i do not have a lecturer etc.

f (x,y) = x2/ √(x2+ y2)

Prove from First principles 
Lim  f(x,y) = 0
(x,y) -> (0,0)

Answer:
The domain Df  ∈ {(x,y) ∈ R}

0 < ll√[(x - 0)2 + (y - 0) 2]ll <     ( from definition ll√[(x - a)2 + (y - b) 2]ll <  )
0 < ll√[(x )2 + (y) 2]ll < 
0 < ll√[(x )2 + (y) 2]ll < 1               (where 1 < )

lx-al = lxl = ll√[(x )2 + (y ) 2]ll = {(x,y) – (0,0)}
ly-bl = lyl = ll√[(x )2 + (y ) 2]ll =  {(x,y) – (0,0)}

lf(x) - L l < ε 
lx2/ √(x2+ y2) – 0 l < ε 
lx2/ √(x2+ y2) – 0 l < ε 
lx2l/l √(x2+ y2)l < ε
lxl 2/ √(x2+ y2) < ε

{√(x2+ y2)}2/ √(x2+ y2) < ε     (substituted in lxl2 = ll√[(x )2 + (y ) 2]ll 
√(x2+ y2) < ε

If  0 < ll√[(x )2 + (y) 2]ll < 1,     where 1 < ,      then lf(x) - L l < ε  for Lim  f(x,y) = 0
(x,y)->(0,0)

Comment: Hi, here is a basic tutorial. Please type math using MathJax. [Gate](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks going there now

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest a much simpler argument. $\delta =\epsilon$ works because $x^{2} \leq {x^{2}+y^{2}}$, so $|f(x,y)| \leq \sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}$. Hence $\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}} <\epsilon$ implies $|f(x,y)| <\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you, i have updated the question i am still struggling with this sites way of doing things. Could you kindly explain?

Comment: @ShaunWeinberg Sorry, I find it very hard to read what you have written. There is nothing wrong in doing some simple manipulations before coming up with a $\delta$, so my answer is usually accepted by any teacher.